# AX 2012 http inbound port activate error – deployment web site was not found for port

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I am new to AX and a beginner to IIS (and first post on stackoverflow). I need some assistance with AX 2012 AIF Web Services and configuring an http AX Inbound Port.

My issue is in trying to activate an Inbound Port within AX using HTTP. I receive the following two errors:

- The deployment web site was not found for port: TestOrdImport
- The port ‘TestOrdImport’ could not be deployed.\nError: The deployment web site was not found for port: TestOrdImport

This is in a test environment using the Microsoft issued AX 2012 FP1 hyper-v image. Someone else installed the web services using the instructions found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg731848.aspx

Based on the person who did the install for the web services I created a new entry in the web sites screen using a virtual directory share path of “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\AifWebServices\” and URL "http://AX2012-A:85/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60"

I am not sure if these are correct the but the web site validates without error. The web services appeared to be installed into site “AIF” rather than the “Default Web Site”

Does anyone see any issues with the IIS configuration of sites? Should the web services been installed into the default web site rather than AIF site?

When creating the Inbound port it needs to be http as I am setting this up per someone’s request but again I cannot get the inbound port to activate and could use some guidance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vicI.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get someone with AX experience to resolve the issue using the HTTP inbound port adapter with AX and the AIF Web Services.

Some key points related to my issue and setting up the inbound port in AIF with the configured AX AIF web sites that might be helpful to others in a similar situation:

Notes on setting up the AIF web sites within AX:

- To get the correct folder (virtual directory) for the actual IIS
  server setup, you must use IIS to find the association (Virtual
  server -> physical disk path).
- The URL must be a valid reference to a real HTTP server that will be servicing this service (port 85 in my case; not port 8101). The AOS hosted WCF services is configured for port 8101.

Notes on setting up the HTTP Inbound Port within AX:

- The site path in the URI for the Inbound port did not match any path
  defined in the “Web sites” configured. The text string must exactly
  match from the “http://...” beginning through to the inbound port
  name (“TestOrdImport/xppservice.svc” portion), using port 85 in my
  example and no “/Services/” in the path since that was for the basic
  inbound ports and “Services” sub-folder is not configured for the IIS
  virtual server. In fact, if you attempt to setup the web site
  configuration with the “Services” sub-folder so that it matches
  correctly there, the web sites form will give you an errors since
  “Services” sub-folder does not exist and if you create it, it does
  not have all the other support files that were installed (the “bin”
  folder and such).
- When deployed successfully and when I use the WSDL URI in the web
  browser, I get back a page stating “You have created a service….” And
  tell you some basics on how to use it (this shows it is installed
  correctly). For HTTP services you always add “?wsdl” to the URI to
  get the actual WSDL document so this URI/URL works correctly for
  that: http://ax2012-a.contoso.com:85/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/TestOrdImport/xppservice.svc?wsdl

It is not much but I hope this helps someone else. Much of the above was written by the person who helped solve my issue.

Comment: as an additional note it looks like the web site name that is setup within AX AIF might be required to match to the IIS name?
I was having similar issues again and deleted and re-added the website with a matching name and it appeared to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be caused by a trailing slash character (/) in the website URL field.
Removing it may resolve this error message.

Source: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axdilip/archive/2015/06/23/troubleshoot-dynamics-ax-2012-aif-error-the-deployment-web-site-was-not-found-for-the-port